# Битрикс | Вывести описание картинки

Tags: php, изображения, битрикс

Есть в шаблоне Битрикса, в template.php, код:

```
<?if($arResult['PROPERTIES']['GALARY']['VALUE']):?>
  <div class="gallery">
    <div class="items clearfix">
      <?
      foreach ($arResult['PROPERTIES']['GALARY']['VALUE'] as $key => $slideID) 
      {
         $imgSRC = CFile::GetPath($slideID);?>
         <div class="item_gallery">
           <a data-fancybox="gallery1" href="<?=$imgSRC?>">
              <div class="pic" style="background-image: url(<?=$imgSRC?>);"></div>
           </a>
        <span class="gal_desc"><?=$arFile["DESCRIPTION"]?></span>
        </div>
        <?
     }
     ?>
  </div>
</div>
<?
endif;
?>
```

Он выводит галерею картинок. Сами картинки идут через свойство инфоблока. И Описание к ним указано.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но вот на сайт само описание не выводится. Видно только пустой `<span class=""></span>`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у вас в коде переменная $arFile  не определена, поэтому там всегда пустота. Посмотрите всё содержимое $arResult найдите нужное вам и подставте в нужном мести шаблона, или в штатном шаблоне найдите как определяется $arFile

Comment: Да, заработало. Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Вот поправила. С подсказки из коммента.

```
<?if($arResult['PROPERTIES']['GALARY']['VALUE']):?>
  <div class="gallery">
    <div class="items clearfix">
      <?
      foreach ($arResult['PROPERTIES']['GALARY']['VALUE'] as $key => $slideID) 
      { $arFile = CFile::GetFileArray($slideID);
         $imgSRC = CFile::GetPath($slideID);?>
         <div class="item_gallery">
           <a data-fancybox="gallery1" href="<?=$imgSRC?>" title="<?=$arFile['DESCRIPTION']?>">
              <div class="pic" style="background-image: url(<?=$imgSRC?>);"></div>
           </a>
        <span class="gal_desc"><?=$arFile["DESCRIPTION"]?></span>
        </div>
        <?
     }
     ?>
  </div>
</div>
<?
endif;
?>
```